# Confused about how Intellij compiles things and deals with resources

Tags: compilation, resources, intellij-idea

I'm quite new to IntelliJ from visual studio, and I'm generally quite confused about how resource files work in an IntelliJ project. I'm read a few questions & answers about getting resources onto the classpath, as well as the IntelliJ docs, but am still confused. I have a few further questions:

1. Some questions mention maven, some not. How do maven projects differ from normal modules in how they compile things and deal with resources?
2. When I run a `main` method from within IntelliJ, where does it run it from? Directly from the compiled `.class` files, or from the generated `jar`? Where do both those exist in the filesystem, and whats the difference?
3. If I just put an `.xml` file somewhere in the source tree, what does IntelliJ do with it by default when compiling and running from within IntelliJ? How can I change where it puts it?
4. What is the classpath when running a `main` function within IntelliJ?
5. How do you get an arbitary file included in a jar file or alongside it in the compiled output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In a Maven project IDE follows Maven rules to process resources so that you will get the consistent results between the command line Maven build and IDEA build. If Maven copies resources to classpath, IDEA will do the same.
2. From the classpath of the module and its dependencies, normally a `.class` file is used.
3. In a non-Maven project resources are copied to the output according to `Settings` | `Compiler` | `Resource Patterns`. In a Maven project resources are handled according to `pom.xml` resources rules. Files from `resources` folder are copied automatically. Other folders need to be added to the resources manually using `pom.xml`.
4. You can view the classpath in the command line that is printed in the Run console.
5. In a Maven project use the `resources` folder. In a non-Maven project the file should be under a source root and its extension needs to be present in the `Resource Patterns` configuration.

Also note that if you are using a legacy compilation (`External Build` disabled), IDEA will use `Resource Patterns` configuration even in Maven projects and the output between IDEA and Maven will be different. The same applies to IDEA 11 and older versions.

Comment: Thanks. What about changing resources from inside a jar to alongside it? What's the default?

Comment: I don't understand your question, please clarify.

Comment: @CrazyCoder : I've the following statement in a main method of a java class. `final ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("integration-context.xml");` And the `integration-context.xml` file in the resource directory. But when I run the main method, IDEA says, file not found.

Comment: Send the sample project to support and describe the problem there.

Comment: Configuring <build>/<resources> works like a charm if you don't need to tweak output dir per resource dir. But if you do and implement it per Maven docs (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html), IDEA seems to be ignoring that. Is there any solution for this? Maybe, I'll file a bug with IDEA.