# Intellij can't find .png

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

My intellij can't find local .png images.

```
private String craft = "craft.png";
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(craft));
```

The .png is located in the same directory as the java files.  I don't understand why it isn't working.  Using maven build, tried alternating from resources to java, but still no luck :(

Comment: IDE's usually start at the root of the project and start looking from there. If you say it is in the same directory as the java files, it makes me think that the image is not at the root of the project directory.

Comment: In the project structure, the Module, its included in the Source Folders.  Both src/main/java and src/main/resources

Comment: Also the root of the directory is not where the java files are.  The java files are located at src/main/java/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`craft.png` must be placed into `src/main/resources`, otherwise it will be not copied to the classpath according to the Maven rules. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17699988/104891) for more details.

Your code should be also changed to:

`private String craft = "/craft.png";`

Here is the [sample working project](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2752840/ShareXmod/2013-09/ResourceSample.zip).

Comment: Yeah, like i said in the description, already tried placing it in there and still no change.  Keep getting NullPointerException...

Comment: No, your original description is different: `The .png is located in the same directory as the java files`. I'm saying that you need to use `src/main/resources` instead of `src/main/java`.

Comment: And here I'm saying : tried alternating from resources to java,

Comment: I am having this same problem. IntelliJ is not finding `src/main/resources/images/foo.jpg`, referenced as *images/foo.jpg*. The application is a `JNLP` webstart that works when launched from the browser (the JRE finds the image in the JNLP jar).

Answer (score 1):

Go to your IntelliJ Preferences and search for "resource patterns" (or just go straight to the "Compiler" settings).

IntelliJ will only copy certain resources to the output directory. Make sure the resource pattern includes *.png.

I have my resource pattern set to !*.java (copy everything that's not a source file) which seems to work fine (and should really be the default, in my opinion).

Comment: Already done this.  I have this on the end of my resource patterns: ;*.png

Answer (score 1):

> tried alternating from resources to java

So at first you tried putting craft.png into `src/main/resources`. That is where it must be put according to Maven (not in src/main/java).

But it didn't work because 
`this.getClass().getResource("craft.png")` tries to find "craft.png" relative to the **this.class's package**. If your *this.class* is in package *foo.bar* then you must put *craft.png* in `src/main/resources/foo/bar/`

You can also provide an absolute path in getResource() by using a leading slash `/`. For example put craft.png into a custom folder under resources `src/main/resources/customFolder/` and read it with the leading slash `/` in front of *customFolder*:
`this.getClass().getResource("/customFolder/craft.png")`

If you don't use leading slash in `getResource()` method then internally class's package name  is prepended to the resource name to make it absolute. 
This behavior is explained in [Class.getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)