# Java - getImage and drawImage do not work for local files

Tags: java, image, intellij-idea

I am working by way through a tutorial: http://www.kilobolt.com/day-4-enter-the-robot.html
and have been having a problem getting a simple image to display in the applet. I am using IntelliJ 13 Community Edition. The main for loading the images is here:

It does the image setup in the init method:

```
public void init() {

    setSize(800, 480);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
    Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
    frame.setTitle("Q-Bot Alpha");
    try {
        base = getDocumentBase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    // Image Setups
    character = getImage(base, "data/character.png").toString());
}
```

where **character** is a sprite I obtained from the tutorial website. I saved it in a folder called data. The file structure can be seen here:
[image]

When I run this I just see a black background and character.png is not displayed. However if I change the getImage line to:

```
character = getImage(base, new URL("http://www.kilobolt.com/uploads/1/2/5/7/12571940/character.png").toString());
```

and point at the URL directly it works. I suspect this must be a path issue but I have not been able to get it working.

Comment: My guess is that the application isn't executed in `src` but in the directory above it, so you would have to point to `src/data/character.png` or move the data directory up a level.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly it did not work either. Is there any way to confirm what directory it is used?

Comment: This question explains how to get the current working directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18601928/104891 for the sample project and the proper way to load resources from the classpath instead of the working directory (that is not set to `src` in your case).

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same program and had the same problem. When run, the document base is actually in KiloboltGame/bin  so you need to add your data/character.png here.