# IDEA can't find the files under custom test source root dir if the project is using maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a project managed by maven, in IDEA. I create a custom dir for intergration tests under "src", and named "intg":

```
myproject
  |- src
      |- intg
      |-   |- java
      |-   |- resources
      |- main
      |-   |- java
      |-   |- resources
      |- test
           |- java
           |- resources
```

In my POM.xml, I added:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/test-classes</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/intg/resources</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then I reimport the POM.xml in IDEA, but I found IDEA doesn't treat the "resources" dir as the test source root dir, so I manually mark it as "test source root".

Then I put a file "test-data.txt" to it, and get it in my test code:

```
@Test
public void shouldGetTheFileFromClasspath() {
   URL resource = MyTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test-data.txt");
   assertNotNull(resource);
}
```

Unfortunately, the test is failed. If I move "test-data.txt" to "src/test/resources", then it will pass.

I'm not sure where is wrong and how to fix it. It has been tormented me a whole day, please help ~

Comment: I've explained how IDEA processes resources in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17699988/104891). Your problem may be caused by [this bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-48247).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/intg/resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
```

Then call "Generate resources and update folders"

Answer (score 0):

As first you should stick with [**Maven directory conventions**](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). However if you insist to do it your way. There is how you can do it:

**1. update your pom.xml**

Mark your `src/intg/java` as source code directory

```
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes><include>**/src/intg/java/**</include></includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Mar your `src/intg/source` as resources directory

```
  <build>
    <!--
    <directory>target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    -->
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/intg/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <!--testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources-->
  </build>
```

**2. setup your idea project**

- right click on `src/intg/java` and **Mark directory as** > **Source root**
- right click on `src/intg/resources` and **Mark directory as** > **Source root**

That's it, you are all set. Both Maven and Idea Junit tests should compile and run.